# How to Track revenues and revenue sharing from Google AdMob through an API

Tags: android, google-api, admob, google-analytics-api

We are Building an Android App which supports Google AdMob,
and in the Back-end I want show the Revenue Share and Revenue from these Ads(Google Ads).

Is there any API to track all these revenue related details.so, that i will track the details and then i can show it in the Back-end pls help me to sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [AdSense Management API](http://developers.google.com/adsense/management/) to get reports on AdSense/Admob earnings.

You can make direct requests,or use the [client libraries and samples](http://developers.google.com/adsense/management/libraries) for your implementation.

[Here is](http://developers.google.com/adsense/management/getting_started) a tutorial on getting started

Answer (score 0):

You also can try an [AdMob API](https://developers.google.com/admob/api) to get the data.